# Add a custom textfield to button_to in addition to data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, button-to

I have a `button_to` called 'DELETE' within which I have added

```
data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete?" }
```

I also wish to add a custom textfield asking the user for appropriate reason before deletion and then store it consequently. Can I add a textfield inside data apart from the default `confirm` or `disabled` option?

I have done it with window.open as of now but it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add additional fields to the confirmation box. Because it gets only single parameter - **message**. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp).

I'd recommend to built a custom confirmation dialog for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) is not the same as [`data: {confirm....}`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html) (although thinking about it, you're probably using `data: {...}` on the `button_to`)

---

If you were using `button_to`, you could add extra parameters to your form by using the `params` option:

```
<%= button_to "Text", your_path, params: {name: "John"} %>
```

As described in the docs, the params are passed as *hidden* fields, and thus should be static data (not editable by the user):

> Hash of parameters to be rendered as hidden fields within the form.

---

Since you wish to use `data: {confirm ...}`, you have to be clear on how it works:

> `confirm: 'question?'` - This will allow the unobtrusive JavaScript driver to prompt with the question specified (in this case, the resulting text would be question?. If the user accepts, the link is processed normally, otherwise no action is taken.

As stated, this loads a ["confirm" JS dialogue](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp), which basically only has `ok/cancel` to determine whether the user wishes to proceed.

You **cannot** send extra parameters through the standard confirmation dialogue.

--

What you *can* do is create a custom confirmation [action for Rails](http://thelazylog.com/custom-dialog-for-data-confirm-in-rails/).

This involves overriding the `$.rails.showConfirmationDialog(link);` method, so instead of invoking a lowly `confirm` dialogue, it can show whatever you need.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenspiel/af1c25835b716205cad2):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.rails.allowAction = function(link) {
  if (link.data('confirm')) {
    $.rails.showConfirmationDialog(link);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(link) {
  link.data('confirm', null);
  return link.trigger('click');
};

$.rails.showConfirmationDialog = function(link) {
  var message, title;
  message = link.data('confirm');
  title = link.data('title') || 'Warning';
  return // ->> your custom action <<-- //
};
```

We use the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var myCustomConfirmBox;
$.rails.allowAction = function(element) {
  var answer, message;
  message = element.data("confirm");
  answer = false;
  if (!message) {
    return true;
  }
  if ($.rails.fire(element, "confirm")) {
    myCustomConfirmBox(element, message, function() {
      var callback, oldAllowAction;
      callback = $.rails.fire(element, "confirm:complete", [answer]);
      if (callback) {
        oldAllowAction = $.rails.allowAction;
        $.rails.allowAction = function() {
          return true;
        };
        element.trigger("click");
        $.rails.allowAction = oldAllowAction;
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
};

myCustomConfirmBox = function(link, message, callback) {
  var flash, icon, wrap;
  if (!($("flash#confirm").length > 0)) {
    icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.className = "fa fa-question-circle";
    flash = document.createElement("flash");
    flash.setAttribute("id", "confirm");
    flash.appendChild(icon);
    flash.className = "animated fadeInDown";
    flash.innerHTML += message;
    wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
    wrap.insertBefore(flash, wrap.childNodes[0]);
    return $(document).on("click", "flash#confirm", function() {
      return callback(link);
    });
  }
};
```

--

If you wanted to pass an extra parameter through this, you'd have to use it in the JS. I've never done it before, but I know you can append it to the query you're sending to your server.

As such, if you update your code to show your routes and controller code, I should be able to come up with an idea on how to pass a param for you.